# Run flutter app tries to find the AndroidManifest.xml file in a wrong place

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, build.gradle

I want to run a flutter app on an Android device. I get the code from the repo, and run the command 'flutter pub get' to obtain the dependencies. After that I tried to run the app but gives my the next error.

Your Flutter application is created using an older version of the Android
embedding. It is being deprecated in favor of Android embedding v2. To migrate
your project, follow the steps at:

The detected reason was:

```
  No `C:\Users\ALBERTO\Desktop\z8-60bd17613eb21c7640572499cd98ad08285a91bf\android\AndroidManifest.xml` file
```

I check that the project was migrated to v2 previously. What I found weird is why it tries to find the AndroidManifest inside Android folder, when the file actually exists on android/app/src/main/ path.

I'm missing some config stuff?

FYI I'm using Android Studio instead of VS Code, but I don't think it matters because I get the same error if I try to run the app from the console.

Answer (score 0):

1. Verify that the `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml` file exists in your project.
2. If the file exists, clean your flutter project by typing the command `flutter clean`, if it doesn't exist then run `flutter create .` this will create all the missing files.
3. Then Rebuilt the project using `flutter run`

Comment: Hi, Nikhil. AndroidManiferst exists on android/app/src/main/ path. I executed flutter clean and flutter run, but the problem persists. If I execute flutter create, will erase all the android platform or only create the missing files and keep the exist ones?

Comment: yes, run flutter create .  it will only create the missing files, nothing will be deleted. The code is ```flutter create .``` (Don't forget the dot)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else who had this issue `flutter create .` did work but the real issue for me is that somehow my android level `build.gradle` had been deleted.